# How to place a view exactly above the center of its parent view/layout in android

Tags: android

What I want to achieve is that I want to place a `View` "above" the center of its parent layout. consider the image below:

[image]

The blue rectangle it where I want my `View` to be. as you can see it is exactly above the (vertical)center of the screen.

The challenge is that we don't know the height of the view (so I can't use a bottom margin for it) and I want to do it in layout `xml` file (so I can't use code to determine the height of the view and set it a margin programmatically)

with these restrictions, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the following layout to place your view at the desired location-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/your_view"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dummy_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `ConstraintLayout`, it can be done using guidelines easily (instead of using a View as the anchor point):

[image: Example]

XML example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/mid_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
            />
    <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#F00"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mid_guideline"
            />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't differ much from the "RelativeLayout technique" which places a View in the center and another one above that one.

Comment: I know, it's the same but using ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout. Matter of taste,  I guess.